# How can I repair a damaged flat 4 pin cable?

Tags: ribbon-cable, touch-panel

I have a computerized sewing machine Juki HZL-009. This picture is related to its screen, whose touch part has a 4-pin resistive touch screen glass panel.

This image is from a healthy screen without any problems. The cable of my touch screen glass panel was damaged and it was too short. My problem is that I don't know how to extend this cable, and most importantly, the cable head should be in its original shape, that is, as you can see in the picture:

[image]

[image]

This is a picture of the damaged cable:

[image]

Comment: What did the supplier/manufacturer advise?

Comment: This touch screen is related to Juki sewing machine, but I have no information about the manufacturer of this panel

Comment: Start by talking to Juki is my advise.

Comment: They said this sewing machine is very old and they do not provide any support

Comment: What's the Juki model number?

Comment: "very old" hah! You can find online service manuals for Singer machines back to about 1900...

Comment: The flex doesn't appear to be damaged in the photo.  It looks scratched up from the connector contacts.  The picture is fuzzy, though, so it might be worse than it looks like in the picture.

Comment: @user_1818839:  Yes, you can find manuals for some very old sewing machines.  You can also run into unobtainable parts for those old machines.  It took me nearly a year to discover that a screw I needed for my Adler 8 sewing machine from 1926 had to be a British Standard Whitworth 1/8 inch.  Right now I am trying to find another screw for a Pfaff model K from 1897.  It's a smidge smaller than an M6, but bigger than an M5.  It may be another Whitworth, but none seem close enough for me to order some.  It may also be some custom thing that only Pfaff used.

Comment: All that to say:  The old machines aren't necessarily better in terms of openness and replacements.

Comment: @JRE : BSW is hardly unobtainable even now. But "repair" in that era would include "turn and thread cut a new part to fit" with a lathe being a standard tool. Perfectly open; we've mostly lost that art. Check the thread angle for your model K : if it's steeper than 60 degrees or Whitworth 55 degrees, it may be a BA thread (47.5 degrees) with 1BA being 5.3mm OD, 0.9mm pitch. Even numbered BA threads are easy to find; odd ones are uncommon but taps and dies are available. (Or it may be a Thury or Loewenherz thread, I've never met those) I'd offer to turn one if I wasn't 6 hours from home.

Comment: @user_1818839:  Repair in that era did indeed include "make a new screw."  The way I discovered that I needed BSW was that I found a book (in German) that detailed the equipment needed to set up a repair shop.  Besides equipment for blueing steel and cutting screw head slots, it was recommended that you have a complete set of taps and dies for metric and BSW.  Up to that point, I'd never heard of BSW - and would never have thought to look up a British standard for a machine made in Germany.  Right now, I don't even know the thread pitch of the needed screw.  I only have the threaded hole.

Comment: I have a set of thread guages ordered.

Comment: BSW is available, but only on order or through speciality shops - of which I know of exactly zero in my part of the world.  In other news, the bobbins for the Adler were proprietary.  Funky shape, special size.  The only way to get them these days is to buy bits and pieces off eBay - or make them yourself, if you have a machine shop (which I don't.)  I've managed to buy about a dozen, which should last for my lifetime, at least.

Comment: https://www.chronos.ltd.uk/product/1ba-carbon-die/
With a nice big hole like that, BluTak and a nail will give you the thread form..

Comment: It is Juki HZL-009

Answer (score 0):

These flat flexible plastic cables break easily, even after a single attempt to reinsert it. Though there are guides to repair them, such as at [Instructables](https://www.instructables.com/Repairing-Flexible-Cable-for-Electronics-Equipment/), old ones may be brittle and likely to break further while attempting repairs.

You might try making your own, if you cannot buy a replacement of the correct pitch and length (e.g., [0.5mm Pitch 76mm FPC FFC Flexible Ribbon Cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RZ8KZ9B)), you might try fabricating your own from thin, varnish-insulated wire sandwiched between layers of cellophane tape, with ends stripped and folded over the outside. That improvised cable would not have the same impedance as the original, but for low-frequency use in a display, should work. It *is* fiddly work keeping the wires parallel while taping, and worse, trying to get all four contacts at each end to stay connected until the case is closed -- tape the cable to the part near each end, to hold it.